# Weekly find events

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to look back two years by week to find if there have been multiple events for a week. Like if 7/1/19-7/8/19 if there was 3 events that member would appear. Is there any way to do this other than a giant case statement for each week? Like `case when event = y and event_date between todate('07/01/2019','mm/dd/yyyy') and todate('07/08/2019','mm/dd/yyyy') then 1 else 0 end`. Would I need to do that for all 104 weeks?

```
select distinct prov
,svcdate
,svccod
,membno
,unitct
from claim
where svcdate > '20170911'
```

That query returns the name- bike shop, svcdate(event date)- '20180812, code - h499, member id- 456, and units- 5

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your DBMS and some example input with desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the week of the year, and the year itself.  The HAVING clause then allows you to filter based on aggregates:

```
--Set up example test table and populate with example data
DECLARE @Events TABLE (eventDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES ('20180101'), ('20180102'), ('20180103')

SELECT DATEPART(wk, eventDate), DATEPART(year, eventDate)
FROM @Events 
WHERE eventDate BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, eventDate), DATEPART(year, eventDate)
having COUNT(1) > 1
```

The above will return the week number and the year, and you can convert that into a more friendly form.

Edit: Having thought about this again - it could depend if a) you're just interested in weeks *with multiple events* or b) *with more than a specified number of events*.  If a), you could adopt a simpler WHERE EXISTS (I wasn't sure what your PK was in that table, so have called it claimID):

```
SELECT * 
FROM claim c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM claim c2 
              WHERE c.claimID > c2.claimID
              and (DATEPART(dw, c.svcdate) = DATEPART(dw, c2.svcdate) AND DATEPART(year, c.svcdate) = DATEPART(year, c2.svcdate))
```

The above falls down if you're after weeks with n or more events in it - then I think the first example works better.

It also depends on what output you're after - are you after the claim rows themselves, or just a list of dates?

Comment: Would I need to add every date for the previous two years? I see you added three days. Thanks

Comment: That's just populating some example test data in a temp table.  Providing you have a table with all your various events and their dates, you'd be using that instead of @T.

Comment: Edited to make the variable and column names a bit more explanatory.

Comment: Ok so would it be values(event_date) and do i create the (at)start_date and end_date or do i just put the beginning and end dates in?

Comment: I'd suggest amending your question to include a example of what your event data looks like.

I'm just using the INSERT VALUES() syntax to hack some test data in so you have a working example to experiment with, you wouldn't need that part of the code - as you already have a table with your events in.

Comment: As for using variables for start_date and end_date, that's just good practise - always best to declare those separately rather than having hard-coded values strewn around the query.